# SQL Column is invalid in ORDER BY, not contained in aggregate or GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT TOP 1 e.EmployeeID
FROM Employees e
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON o.EMployeeID = e.EmployeeID
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT OrderID,
             SUM((UnitPrice * Quantity) - Discount) AS TotalOrderPrice
      FROM [Order Details]
      GROUP BY OrderID
    ) oi ON oi.OrderID = o.OrderID
GROUP BY e.employeeid
ORDER BY TotalOrderPrice * 0.1 DESC,
         COUNT(o.OrderID) ASC
```

> Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>
> Column "oi.TotalOrderPrice" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: -1 Tagging `mysql` and `sql-server`

Comment: Why `ORDER BY TotalOrderPrice * 0.1`and not `ORDER BY TotalOrderPrice` ?

Comment: The error message is reasonable straightforward. You've grouped *multiple* rows with the same `EmployeeID` and potentially *different* `TotalOrderPrice` values into a single row. Which of those values should it be using?

Answer (score 4):

If you use a `GROUP BY`, you can only `SELECT` (and thus, `ORDER`) the columns, which are

1. Either one of the columns you grouped by with
2. Either is an aggregate function (for example, `MAX()` or `COUNT()`)

MySQL hasn't this limitation, but it is only a MySQL-specific extension to the SQL standard. Any other SQL server, included the Microsoft SQL, have this.