# (stored Procedure) How to ordering special sequence

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a question how to make an ordering by sequence

```
select * from (select @fYear as [Year],
(case when main.Description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
 else main.Description
 end) as description,

  --CardType,
  sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan_Collection,
  sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb_Collection,
 ...

 from tblR as main
 left join tblP as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
 left join tblB as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear

  group by  (case when description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
   else main.Description
```

end)

```
  ) t 
 order by (case when t.description =  'Amanah' then 1
                               when t.description = 'Mah' then 2
                               when t.description = 'JK' then 3
                               END) ASC
```

This output look like:

[image]

need to follow the order sequence like:

[image]

I get this error:

> is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in
>   either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Thanks all.

Comment: the expression in `ORDER BY` (`CASE` expression) has to match the one in the select and group-by list (description column). If you need to sort by something that you won't return, still add the sort expression as a result column.

Comment: not very sure how you say.. can you explain more detail?

Comment: Which dbms are you uisng? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: @jarlh: I using sql server

Comment: please provide what exactly you need? which rules for `order by`?

Comment: The error message says it all. When GROUP BY, you can only specify selectet columns in the ORDER BY.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Column is invalid in ORDER BY, not contained in aggregate or GROUP BY](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23287125/sql-column-is-invalid-in-order-by-not-contained-in-aggregate-or-group-by)

Comment: we should have canonical answer for this, like the famous nullreferenceexception. googling "site:stackoverflow.com invalid in the order by clause" turns up many specific "help me fix this code"-type posts, but only a few answers explain the common principle. I have now flagged this as a duplicate of one of those, which seems to fit best.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use below query instead :

```
select * from (select @fYear as [Year],
(case when main.Description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
     else main.Description
end) as description,

--CardType,
sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as Jan_Collection,
sum(case when MONTH(blue.AppliedDate) = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as Feb_Collection,
...

from tblR as main
left join tblP as b on  main.requestorid = b.requestorid
left join tblB as blue on b.partyid = blue.partyid and YEAR(blue.AppliedDate) = @fYear

group by  (case when description in ('Kecil', 'Tanah') then 'JK'
       else main.Description
  end)

) t 
  order by (case when t.description =  'Amanah' then 1
                                   when t.description = 'Mah' then 2
                                   when t.description = 'JK' then 3
                                   END) ASC
```

Comment: still same error  in  `case when description =  'Amanah' then 1
                                   when description = 'Mah' then 2
                                   when description = 'JK' then 3
                                   END as orderColumn`

Comment: Please check answer again,  as you dont use group by where order by using.

Comment: it is my pleasure to help you.